# C++ double free or corruption (out): Even with copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

my code is producing 
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffe400eb0e0 ***

Whenever it's run, i assumed this was an issue based on either my copy constructor or how I delete my dynamic array but i'm having trouble working out where the issue arises:

My Class:

```
class Student {
  public:
    Student();
    Student(const Student&);
    Student & operator= (const Student&);
    ~Student();
    void setStudentData(int *, int &, int, string);
    int getNumOfSubjTaken();
    int getAverageMark();
    int getLowestMark();
    int getHighestMark();
    string getFullName();
    void sortMarks(int &);

  private:
    string fullName;
    int *marks;
    int numOfSubjects;

};
```

Copy Constructor:

```
Student::Student(const Student& pupil) {
  marks = new int[numOfSubjects = pupil.numOfSubjects];
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubjects; i++) {
   marks[i] = pupil.marks[i];
  }
  fullName = pupil.fullName;
  //removed after edit: marks = pupil.marks;
}
```

Assignment Operator:

```
Student &Student::operator=(const Student &pupil) {
 if (this != &pupil) {
   for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubjects; i++) {
     marks[i] = pupil.marks[i];
     }
   fullName = pupil.fullName;
    numOfSubjects = pupil.numOfSubjects;
    marks = pupil.marks;
 }
  return *this;
```

}

Deconstructor:

```
Student::~Student(){
 if (marks != NULL) {
   delete [] marks;
 }
  marks = NULL;
  numOfSubjects = 0;
  fullName = "";
}
```

Set Function (Mutator):

```
 void Student::setStudentData(int *markArray, int &numStudents, int numSub, string fullName) {

  marks = new int[numSub];
  for (int i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    marks[i] = markArray[i];
  }

   this->numOfSubjects = numSub;
   this->fullName = fullName;
}
```

And it was only after i implemented my write function that this issue was occurring:

```
void writeFile(fstream &fout, char *argv[], Student *pupil, int &numRecs)        {
  const char sep = ' ';
  const int nameWidth = 5;
  const int numWidth = 7;

  fout.open(argv[2]);

 if (!fout.good()) {
    cout << "Error: Invalid data in " << argv[1] << " file." << endl;
    cout << "The program is terminated.";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else {
    // creating the table output
    fout << left << setw(nameWidth) << setfill(sep) << "Full Name";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "mark1";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "mark2";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "mark3";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "mark4";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "average";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "min";
    fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "max";
    fout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numRecs; i++) { //numRecs being number of records/students
      fout << left << setw(nameWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].getFullName();
      for (int j = 0; j < pupil[i].getNumOfSubjTaken(); j++) { //writes each mark up to
        //fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].marks[j];
    //This line doesn't work, but i need to be able to write the marks.
  }
  if (pupil[i].getNumOfSubjTaken() < 4) {
    for (int k = pupil[i].getNumOfSubjTaken(); k != 4; k++) {
      fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << "  ";
    }
  }
  fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].getAverageMark();
  fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].getLowestMark();
  fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].getHighestMark();
  fout << endl;
}

  }
}
```

I also can't seem to fout << pupil[i].marks[j]; even though it should work.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Where is the destructor?  Also, your assignment operator has a memory leak as you failed to deallocate the previous memory (and reallocate new memory).  But why do all of that work in the assignment operator when you can simply do [copy / swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)?

Comment: Also, your destructor can simply be `Student::~Student() {delete [] marks;}`.  There is no need to check for NULL, and it makes no sense assigning values to members of an object that's being destroyed.

Comment: `marks = pupil.marks;` in the assignment operator is wrong. `setStudentData` leaks any old data, and doesn't set  `numOfSubjects`., and doesn't use 2 of its parameters

Answer (score 4):

Your assignment operator is incorrect, as it only does a shallow copy of the `marks` pointer.  Thus you will get a double-free error since the `marks` pointer in both objects (`this` and `pupil`) will be pointing to the same memory when the destructor is called on these objects.

Note that if you used `std::vector<int> marks;` instead of `int *marks;`, then there would be no need for a copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor, as a `std::vector<int>` basically does what you're attempting to do in your copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor.  The difference would be that `std::vector<int>` does it safely, efficiently, and all without mistakes.

Having said this, a fix (not the only possible fix) to your code would be to allocate new memory that matches the number of subjects of the passed-in `Student` object, deallocate the `marks` memory, and then assign `marks` to the newly allocated memory with the copied data.

```
Student &Student::operator=(const Student &pupil) 
{
   if (this != &pupil) 
   {
       // allocate new memory and copy
       int *temp = new int [pupil.numOfSubjects];
       for (int i = 0; i < pupil.numOfSubjects; i++) 
           temp[i] = pupil.marks[i];

       // deallocate old memory and assign
       delete [] marks;
       marks = temp;
       fullName = pupil.fullName;
       numOfSubjects = pupil.numOfSubjects;
   }
   return *this;
}
```

---

As an alternate to the above code, since you seem to have a working copy constructor and destructor (necessary for the following to work correctly), an easier solution is to use the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Student &Student::operator=(const Student &pupil) 
{
   Student temp(pupil);
   std::swap(temp.numOfSubjects, numOfSubjects);
   std::swap(temp.marks, marks);
   std::swap(temp.fullName, fullName);
   return *this;
}
```

This utilizes the copy constructor and destructor to create a temporary object, and then swap out the internals of `this` with the temporary object's internals.  Then the temporary object dies off with the old internals.

Comment: Thank you so much for you detailed explanation and fast responses! Unfortunately even after i alter the copy constructor I'm still returned with the same error.

Comment: Then you need to post a [mcve].  Your `setStudentData` function was not posted, and I wouldn't be surprised if this is also faulty.  But why does your `Student` class not have a constructor that takes the student data?  Regardless, the answer given needs to be done to fix any problem with copying and assignment of the `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array that can be resized, the STL already provides one. You can use `std::vector<int>` instead of manipulating memory yourself.

---

I've read your copy constructor and it seems fine.
While we're at it, I think you should also make a move constructor.

---

In your assignment operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubjects; i++) {
    marks[i] = pupil.marks[i];
}
```

fullName = pupil.fullName;
   numOfSubjects = pupil.numOfSubjects;
   marks = pupil.marks;

- You don't allocate `this->mark`. What if `pupil.marks` isn't the same size as `this->marks`?
- The loop can doesn't copy the entirety of `pupil.marks` - only as much as `this->marks` can hold.
- You copy things to `this->marks` (which is good, a deep copy) but then you do `marks = pupil.marks`.

  - The deep copy becomes redundant
  - It makes both `this` and `pupil` "own" the same `marks`, meaning both will try to deallocate it in their destructor, causing your issue.
  - This line introduces a memory leak.

---

In your destructor:

```
if (marks != NULL) {
    delete [] marks;
}
marks = NULL;
numOfSubjects = 0;
fullName = "";
```

- Comparing a pointer to `NULL` is a C way of doing things. It's basically a macro that's usually equals 0. It's more correct to compare to `nullptr`.
- There's no need to set `marks` to `nullptr` after you've deallocated it. No point assigning to the rest of the members either.

---

In your meaty function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRecs; i++) {
    //numRecs being number of records/students
    fout << left << setw(nameWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].getFullName();
    for (int j = 0; j < pupil[i].getNumOfSubjTaken(); j++) {
        fout << left << setw(numWidth) << setfill(sep) << pupil[i].marks[j];
    }
}
```

- If `numRecs` is bigger than the size of the `pupil` array, you get an overflow.

---

All of those points are a cause for bug(s).

Comment: *"It's more correct to compare to `nullptr`."* - Arguably, it's more correct to not compare the pointer against `nullptr`. It is safe to call `operator delete[]` on a `nullptr`, which results in a no-op.